# Cockroach Db Inner join

Tags: sql, cockroachdb

I have 2 tables named As A, B.

A- type,channel1,channel2,channel3
where type is PK.

B-id,type,channel2,channel3
where id is Pk and type is FK

now i want to copy the two columns channel2 and channel 3 into table B from table A. what should i do as cockroach does not support this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Saying you want to "copy" the columns is ambiguous, for SQL related questions, you should specify where you want to insert or update the data, but I'll try to split the difference by suggesting the following:

```
UPSERT into b(type, channel2, channel3)
  SELECT b.type, a.channel2, a.channel3 
    FROM b, a WHERE b.type=a.type;
```

Note if you have a lot of rows, cockroach would prefer that you split this up into multiple updates by adding range conditionals in the where clause.